# Not getting user details in apple authentication while login(React Native)?

Tags: react-native, user-data

**I need help fetching user data while Apple login. I have been trying to login using apple authentication(React Native). But I am not getting any user details so I cannot go ahead and do the rest of it. So can someone please help what I did wrong in this code.**

**Imported libraries:**

import { appleAuth, AppleButton ,
AppleAuthRequestOperation,
AppleAuthRequestScope,
AppleAuthCredentialState,
AppleAuthError,} from '@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

````
export default class AppleLogin extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.authCredentialListener = null;
        this.user = null;
        this.state = {
          credentialStateForUser: -1,
        }
      }
      componentDidMount() {
       
        this.authCredentialListener = appleAuth.onCredentialRevoked(async () => {
          console.log('Credential Revoked');
          this.fetchAndUpdateCredentialState().catch(error =>
            this.setState({ credentialStateForUser: `Error: ${error.code}` }),
          );
        });
    
        this.fetchAndUpdateCredentialState()
          .then(res => this.setState({ credentialStateForUser: res }))
          .catch(error => this.setState({ credentialStateForUser: `Error: ${error.code}` }))
      }
    
      componentWillUnmount() {
      
        this.authCredentialListener();
      }
    
      signIn = async () => {
        console.warn('Beginning Apple Authentication');
    
        // start a login request
        try {
          const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
            requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
            requestedScopes: [
              appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL,
              appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME,
            ],
          });
        
          console.log('appleAuthRequestResponse', appleAuthRequestResponse);

          const {
         newUser,
            email,
            nonce,
            identityToken,
            realUserStatus /* etc */,
          } = jwt_decode(appleAuthRequestResponse.identityToken);
          alert("appleAuthRequestResponse2",email,user)
          this.user = newUser;
          alert("appleAuthRequestResponse 3",this.user )
          this.fetchAndUpdateCredentialState()
            .then(res => {alert('res',res),
            this.setState({ credentialStateForUser: res })})
            .catch(error =>
              this.setState({ credentialStateForUser: `Error: ${error.code}` }),
            );
    
    
          if (realUserStatus === appleAuth.UserStatus.LIKELY_REAL) {
            console.log("I'm a real person!");
          }
    
          console.warn(`Apple Authentication Completed, ${this.user}, ${email}`);
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.code === appleAuth.Error.CANCELED) {
            console.warn('User canceled Apple Sign in.');
          } else {
            console.error(error);
          }
        }
      };
    
      fetchAndUpdateCredentialState = async () => {
        if (this.user === null) {
          this.setState({ credentialStateForUser: 'N/A' });
        } else {
          const credentialState = await appleAuth.getCredentialStateForUser(this.user);
          if (credentialState === appleAuth.State.AUTHORIZED) {
            this.setState({ credentialStateForUser: 'AUTHORIZED' });
          } else {
            this.setState({ credentialStateForUser: credentialState });
          }
        }
      }
    login= async () => {
      const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
        requestedOperation: AppleAuthRequestOperation.LOGIN,
        requestedScopes: [AppleAuthRequestScope.EMAIL, AppleAuthRequestScope.FULL_NAME],
      });
    
      const credentialState = await appleAuth.getCredentialStateForUser(appleAuthRequestResponse.user);
    
      if (credentialState === AppleAuthCredentialState.AUTHORIZED) {
        alert("get cridential",credentialState)
     
      }
      
      // catch signIn errors
   
        if (error.code === AppleAuthError.CANCELED) // do something
        {
          alert("errr",error)
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 1):

To get user details ,you don't need to decode JWT here.

Just de-structure the params or details you want from **appleAuthRequestResponse** object.

```
const {
        user: newUser,
        email,
        fullName,
        nonce,
        identityToken,
        authorizationCode,
        realUserStatus,
      } = appleAuthRequestResponse;
```

Note: Apple provides user details like name and email only once. So if you already did an auth action , you will get email and name undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Use await before jwt_decode:

`const { email } = await jwt_decode(appleAuthRequestResponse.identityToken);`

Comment: With this you can get email and other parameters even if user tries to login again in the app.

Comment: I didnt get a email prop to destructure from this. I get 'aud', 'auth_time', 'c_hash', 'exp', 'iat', 'iss', 'nonce_supported', 'sub'.

Answer (score 0):

In React This library `@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication`

Add this function to your component file

```
export async function appleLogin() {
    // performs login request
    const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
        requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
        requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL, appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME],
      });
       if (!appleAuthRequestResponse.identityToken) {
        throw 'Apple Sign-In failed - no identify token returned';
    }
     // get current authentication state for user
    // /!\ This method must be tested on a real device. On the iOS simulator it always throws an error.
    const credentialState = await appleAuth.getCredentialStateForUser(appleAuthRequestResponse.user);
    //const { email } = await jwt_decode(appleAuthRequestResponse.identityToken); 
   // console.log("email",email)
  
    // use credentialState response to ensure the user is authenticated
    if (credentialState === appleAuth.State.AUTHORIZED) {
      
    }
return appleAuthRequestResponse
}
```

When you use that function (Get all deails)

```
 appleLogin().then((res) => {
                  console.log('Apple Auth data is :', res)
                  Alert.alert('You need to...',res.email)
                  console.log("User Details:->","ID:--",res.user,"Email:--",res.email,"First & Last Name:--",res.givenName + res.familyName)
                 })
```

*Note* : only once you for email and name. So store in your DB.